# python : use optparse on given list rather than on system command line arguments

Tags: python

within the frame of a python application, I need to make calls to several of my scripts that were largely using `optparse`. They all have an entry point of this form :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mains(sys.argv)
```

I just called my main function `mains` thinking that my problem initially came from there. Then, the `mains` always start like that, as an example :

```
def mains( argv ):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename", help="write result to FILE", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-x", "--filter", dest="filterset", help="filters", metavar="FILTERS")
    parser.add_option("-n", "--nameonly", dest="nameonly", help="nameonly", metavar="NAME_ONLY")
    parser.add_option("-z", "--ignorezeros", dest="ignorezeros", help="ignorezeros", metavar="IGNORE_ZEROS")
    parser.add_option("-y", "--xfilter", dest="xfilter", help="xfilter", metavar="X_FILTERS")
```

The argv here isn't used by `optparser`, I do not find how to pass it to it. From my actual principal script, I thought I could call these `mains` by just passing the arguments as a list. Obvioulsy, in the current state the sub scripts will always pick up the command line... How to pass the arguments myself instead ?

UPDATE : my script trying to make those calls to subcripts is called this way from the console :

```
start.py -df
```

The problem : optparse from the first subscript tells me that "d" is not a valid option, which shows it is picking the console arguments at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the call to parse your options:

```
parser.parse_args(argv)
```

parse_args takes an optional argument which will be used for parsing rather than sys.argv.

Answer (score 2):

Although others have answered your immediate question, I would *strongly* recommend putting all your argument-parsing stuff in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` section of your script rather than in the `main()` function. Your `main()` function should behave more like a normal Python function. That way, if you need to call it from another module, you don't have to fake up an `argv` and pretend you're calling it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the argument list as a single argument, you have to define `mains` as

```
def mains(*args):
    ...
```

instead and call it via

```
mains(*sys.argv)
```

Comment: But I don't want the sys.argv, I want my list to be considered as arguments, i.e. different lists for different subscript calls

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer from http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

> (If you like, you can pass a custom argument list to `parse_args()`, but that’s rarely necessary: by default it uses `sys.argv[1:]`.)

instead of:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

do:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

possible chop off the first item if it is the program name